# Find the smallest element in an array.

Tags: java, arrays, methods, invoke

I think the problem lies with the invoking of the method or the braces, not 100% sure. When I call the method does it matter if it before or after the main method?

```
 public class varb
    {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {   
    double[] array = new double [10]; 
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter" + " " + array.length + " numbers");
    for (int c = 0;c<array.length;c++)
    {
    array[c] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    min(array);
    double min(double[] array)
    {
    int i;
    double min = array[0];
    for(i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
     {
    if(min > array[i])
      {
    min = array[i];
      }
     }
    return min;
      } 
     }
    }
```

Comment: format the code properly.

Comment: Please follow code conventions: Java Class names should start with uppercase

Comment: @user3081791 in your code some duplicate code i've deleted that plz check your code is it proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of main does not matter, it can be placed anywhere in the class, generally convention is to place it as the first method or last method in the class.

You code has severe formatting problems, you should always use and IDE, like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) to avoid such issues.
Fixed your code below:

```
public class Varb{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] array = new double[10];
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter" + " " + array.length + " numbers");
        for (int c = 0; c < array.length; c++) {
            array[c] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        min(array);
    }

    private static double min(double[] array) {
        double min = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < min) {
                min = array[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: you make code really simple. i think now he/she can able to understand it easily. good.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** declare a method inside another one.

In your code you try to declare `double min(double[] array)` inside your `main` method.