# Why the output is 0 for a[0] instead of -1?

Tags: java

I am new to java array, I would like to calculate small element in an array when array contains negative elements.

```
class test_array {
    //test_array class  
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] a = {4, 2, 99, 9, -1, 0};           
        int small = a[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {                                       
            if(a[i]<small) {                       
                a[0]=a[i];                         
                a[i]=small;
            } 
        }

        System.out.println(a[0]);       
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try `if(a[i] < small) { small = a[i]; }` `System.out.println(small);`

Comment: @Shiv_k there are vatious ways to find smallest from an array. Your approach is based on shifting the smallest at the 0th index, I have included your approach in my answer and also have told an alternate solution, hope it will be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/42082621/504133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int small = a[0];
```

here you gave 4 to small

you didn't change this value if you find a smaller one. Instead of that you are changing smaller one into this value by

```
a[i] = small;
```

this code and small value doesn't change at all. Your 'small' value is always 4.

when it compares a[5] and small (it means 0 and 4) it passes if statement and makes a[0]=a[5] ( gives it '0').

You are comparing only with first char of array with this algoryhtm but you need to compare it with a dynamic "small" value. Change code like that.

```
class test_array {
//test_array class  

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            int[] a={4,2,99,9,-1,0};           
            int small=a[0];

        for (int i=1;i<a.length;i++)               
        {                                      
            if(a[i]<small)
            {                                             
                small=a[i];
            } 
        }

        System.out.println(small);       
    }   
}
```

Choose first array element as small, then compare. If there is any smaller value, give this value to 'small'. Do it in a loop for all array and find smallest value.

Bonus: Btw it's good to work on simple algorythms like that for starting but know that for hard times there is easier way to sort arrays and find min and max values like

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

It will sort all array. Then arr[0] will be min and arr[arr.lenght-1] will be max values.

Comment: It would be better if we use built-in function which can reduce the lines if code and will be much faster compared to this approach

Answer (score 1):

Though there are various ways to find the smallest element from an array but lets focus on your method. Your method brings the smallest element at the 0th index. You do not need the variable `small`, Also you need to modify the code inside the if condition as below.

```
if(a[i]<a[0]){                    
       int temp = a[i];
       a[i] = a[0];
       a[0] = temp;                    
}
```

Above will shift the smallest element at the 0th index. Other way simply keep assigning the smaller element as you get while iterating the array in a variable and after the loop execution completes, you can use the smallest element. This alternate approach is more efficient if you just want to know the smallest element, as it does not involve shifting of elements. This approach is mentioned by @ReadyFreddy
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082585/504133

Answer (score 0):

You are confused whether you want to keep the smallest element in the variable "small" or in the 0th element of the array.  You are changing a[0] but comparing to small.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing the last element which is compared.

**Iteration 1**

```
i =1
a[1]=2
small =4
a[1]<small  -> a[0] =2 a[1] -> 4
```

**Iteration 2**

```
i =2
a[2]=99
small =4
a[2]<small  // False
```

**Iteration 3**

```
i =3
a[3]=9
small =4
a[3]<small  // False
```

**Iteration 4**

```
i =4
a[4]=-1
small =4
a[4]<small  -> a[0] =-1 a[4] -> 4
```

**Iteration 5**

```
i =5
a[5]=0
small =4
a[5]<small  -> a[0] =0 a[5] -> 4
```

In the last iteration `a[0]` will become 0 and when you print it outside the loop it displays 0.

If you are looking to find the smallest element in the array please refer [Find the smallest element in an array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465001/find-the-smallest-element-in-an-array#answer-20465298)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something different hope this is much simpler to compare and find the least element in the array.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] a = { 4, 2, 99, 1, -2, 0 };
        Arrays.sort(a);
        System.out.println(a[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Please let me know if this code if efficient or not?